# How to "dampen" MultibodyPlant's compliant contact model in a simulation?

Tags: python, drake

### TL;DR

At present, I'm tinkering with a simple clutter-generation Python script.

Where can I find information on how to best "minimize" energy in a plant that I wish to forward simulate, possibly by "damping" the parameters for `MultibodyPlant`'s contact model?

My desire is to be able to forward simulate clutter falling into a sink (or bin), and effectively have the kinetic energy be dampened out (i.e. no bouncing), in such a way that hopefully doesn't make the integration too stiff. For now, I'm fine if this is a "non-physical" hack.

I have seen the following Doxygen sections:

- [Doxygen C++: Contact Modeling in Drake](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/group__drake__contacts.html)
- [Doxygen C++: `MultibodyPlant`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html) - that's where I got the reference to contact modeling and all.

I see options for changing stiction tolerance (in my mind, I would want less slipping, but decreasing this would cause more assertion failures?), as well as time step (accuracy / stiffness, at the trade-off of computation time). I have not yet come across damping terms that I can tune.

One option I have in mind too is to just use `AdvanceTo(t + dt)`, and in between steps, do some simple heuristics to "remove" energy (e.g. see if there was a direction change, and strip out velocity if there was). My guess is this won't really help computation time if the system is still stiff.

### Background

Effectively, this script is just porting a form of Naveen's prior library (which was in the attic, used `RigidBodyTree`) to use `MultibodyPlant`:

[`drake@f2808c7a:attic/manipulation/scene_generation`](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/tree/f2808c7a/attic/manipulation/scene_generation)

My goal is to have quick computation (via wall clock time) to generate novel clutter scenes that are "settled" to a certain extent.

I have a simple toy example working (I can spawn and drop objects into a kitchen sink), but have found that in order to spawn objects where their initial conditions do not cause non-physical behavior / numeric instability (e.g. interpenetrating objects), I am injecting too much "energy" into the system (I spawn them within a box in the xy-plane, but I space them out along z s.t. the initial configuration has no penetration).

I am toying with different ways to "minimize" that energy and make the objects settle with as little compute time as possible.

Some things I've tried briefly:

1. Just forward-simulate within non-penetrating initial conditions. This is fine, but (possibly due to settings in the compliant contact model) it can take a while to settle, and/or there's so much energy that objects will bounce out of the sink. On the "take a while" part,
2. Use the Anzu version of the-soon-to-be-published [Collision Remover](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/13308), with "zero-height" of all objects as the starting point, and the original spawning height as the "collision free" state. This works, but can be computationally expensive for a large number of objects (>5), and overall much slower than just using forward simulation to settle the objects.
3. Try to write a naive height-minimizing `MathematicalProgram` in conjunction using `MinimumDistanceConstraint`. This is slow and rather brittle, though possible it could use more tuning. [Example code here](https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/blob/c1698b905f8597c9079a1892bd8291f2ac6613f4/drake_stuff/multibody_hacks/multibody_plant_energy_hacks.py#L45-L46).

*Disclaimer*: I am a TRI Anzu / Drake Developer, but just ignorant of the more intricate parts of Drake's physical simulation setup :P

Comment: Possible answer: Under the "Contact modeling" section, there is the computation for "Penalty method point contact", specifically the normal force: `fₙ = k(1+dẋ)x`. I will have to check and see if this does anything of what I want.

Comment: Best for these problems would be an analysis type that tackles the problem directly -- you could imagine an optimization: find q that minimizes accelerations (with v=0 always). That's commonly called "static analysis"; Matlab has a "trim" function for that purpose (https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/trim.html). That would be a great Drake feature also. But meanwhile there are lots of things to try -- an easy one would be to add damping to every body (a spatial force that opposes translation and rotation of anything), which is like simulating in molasses.

Comment: A little damping at first, run for a while, increase the damping, repeat will (eventually) settle into a static equilibrium. Not sure whether it would be fast enough for your purposes.

Comment: Along what Sherm said, a quick solution would be having some sort of "drag" on each body. Something we can easily implement with a ForceElement, see [ #13258](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/13258)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always thought that the "right" solution to this is to write a small mathematical program that solves for the fixed point (static equilibrium: v=v̇=0) of the problem.  For the manipulator equations, when v=0 a bunch of the terms disappear.  Solving this globally is ugly and non-convex, but once you know which forces should be non-zero (perhaps by simulating a little), then it should be quite fast, I would think.

Comment: FTR [C++ API](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/dir_bd08a370beeb74038c8d9ad70b7a29c4.html), and related issue for the Python side of things: [drake#13743](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/13473) - specifically,  there's `StaticEquilibriumConstraint`!

Answer (score 0):

Thank y'all for the answers!

For the time being, I went the (sadder) hack route, which is even simpler heuristics:

[`generate_poses_sink_clutter.py`, `height_heuristic(...)`](https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/blob/6e63acdedf16d1a3ac8ac31198468e6adeac1a5f/drake_stuff/multibody_plant_prototypes/generate_poses_sink_clutter.py#L301-L357)

https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/13332#issuecomment-632335186

In this case, the height heuristic runs in about 5ms (even in Python), while the `MathematicalProgram` variants (at least the poor-man versions I wrote) tend to take >500ms.

Would love to come back and revisit this!