# MathematicalProgram with MinimumDistanceConstraint: can you use more general convex shapes with AutoDiff?

Tags: drake

I'm trying to port trajectory optimization code originally written for [TrajOpt](http://rll.berkeley.edu/trajopt) into Drake. One of the nice things about TrajOpt is that it could solve SQP trajectory optimization problems with a constraint enforcing a minimum distance between the robot and surrounding obstacles, and it supported a pretty broad range of geometries (all the standard convex primitives plus simple convex meshes). For a number of reasons, TrajOpt is no longer the right choice for my project, so I'm porting my trajectory optimization code over to Drake. I think `MinimumDistanceConstraint` is what I want to replicate this functionality, but it seems that Drake allows `AutoDiffXd` signed distance queries only for spheres and half-spaces, not for more general convex shapes (like boxes or cylinders).

All of my other constraints support AutoDiff (I have some custom constraints for "probability of collision," but those provide an analytical derivative that can be used in an AutoDiff). In order to add a `MinimumDistanceConstraint` that supports more general geometry, would I have to formulate the `MathematicalProgram` entirely with doubles? Would that slow down the performance of the solver (e.g. by having to do finite differences instead of using the gradient information in `AutoDiffXd`)?

In an ideal world, I'd like to avoid resorting to "bubble-wrapping" my robot and environment (replacing all the collision geometry with spheres), since the runtime of the custom constraints I'm using scales with the number of collide-able pairs in the scene (I'm currently using convex geometry to keep this number relatively low).

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but it seems that Drake allows AutoDiffXd signed distance queries only for spheres and half-spaces, not for more general convex shapes (like boxes or cylinders)

1. I think `MinimumDistanceConstraint` can handle more general geometries (including boxes and cylinders) for `MultibodyPlant<double>` and `SceneGraph<double>`. It calls FCL to compute the signed distance between these geometries (including witness points). It is true that these signed distance queries don't support AutodiffXd yet, but only double type. But as you will see later, you don't need the signed distance query with AutoDiffXd to compute the gradient of the distance.
2. You could try to construct MinimumDistanceConstraint for a `MultibodyPlant<double>` with this [API](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/b061d8fcba502466b8c9d0bb8896e208e85ce1fd/multibody/inverse_kinematics/minimum_distance_constraint.h#L88-L92). Although you use `MultibodyPlant<double>` not `MultibodyPlant<AutoDiffXd>`, `MinimumDistanceConstraint` can still evaluate with AutodiffXd. Specifically, it computes the gradient of the signed distance [here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/b061d8fcba502466b8c9d0bb8896e208e85ce1fd/multibody/inverse_kinematics/distance_constraint_utilities.cc#L8-L43). To compute the gradient of the signed distance query, the signed distance query doesn't need to support AutoDiffXd. We can compute the gradient using the witness points and the normal vectors as

   ```
   ∂d / ∂q = n̂_BA_Wᵀ * (∂p_CbCa_W / ∂q)
   ```

   where `d` is the signed distance, `q` is the robot posture, `n̂_BA_W` is the contact normal, and `∂p_CbCa_W / ∂q` is the Jacobian of the vector from witness point on body B to the witness point on body A. With this gradient,  we solved collision-free inverse kinematics problem with `MultibodyPlant<double>`.

Comment: On (1), I had tried cylinders (see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61841013/7829525) and it wasn't enabled, [see these lines](https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/blob/c1698b905f8597c9079a1892bd8291f2ac6613f4/drake_stuff/multibody_hacks/multibody_plant_energy_hacks.py#L70-L73). On (2), that's what I ended up doing as well, and it worked! (though I ended up abandoning the min-distance constraint formulation, at least for the time being.)